# Python: Overflow encounted in multiply

Tags: python, overflow, recurrent-neural-network

In the process of calculating tanh derivative, dout is the upstream gradient.

tanh(x) = (exp(2*x) - 1)/(exp(2*x)+1)

```
# this will encounter overflow in multiply
d_tanh = dout * 4 * np.exp(2*x)/((np.exp(2*x)+1) * (np.exp(2*x)+1))

# this will not, why?
d_tanh = dout * (1 - np.tanh(x) * np.tanh(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the overflow is caused by a Division by Zero error. Check your 1//((np.exp(2*x)+1) * (np.exp(2*x)+1)) part of the equation. In the second equation there is no divisor so no possible DBZ error.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but (exp(2*x)+1) can't be zero in any circumstance, so Division by Zero error will not occur.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that! exp(0) = 1. Thanks for pointing that out imcaozi!